# how to get anchor tag href attribute when it's hidden with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, url, href

I'm currently using Selenium to make a simple python crawler.

Is there any method that I can get a link address(url) of a anchor tag? When I see the html source, it's hidden just like :

```
<a id='foo' href='#'></a>
```

I can actually click and load the page and get the url address, but then I need to wait a while.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: get_attribute() can work for now but if page gets redirected then you must have to wait and get `URL` address is advisable.

Comment: @AshishKamble Is there any way I can get the address before redirected?

Comment: @J.Victor yes String url = element.get_attribute("href"); will give you URL before redirection. i was saying because you may get redirection that can happen necessary not happens always.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML you have shared :

```
<a id='foo' href='#'></a>
```

You can have a **web element** like this :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
```

once you have the web element, you can get the attribute like this :

```
href_val = element.get_attribute("href")
print(href_val)
```

Comment: That's going to return "#", yes? I think OP is wanting to know how to get the final, redirected URL from the original page without having to click on the link and follow it.

Comment: @JeffC : True, it would return # in this case. I'll be struggling to understand why does OP wants to know the URL , without click and follow ?

Comment: Because click and follow takes time... it would ideal to just be able to get the URL without the extra seconds it would take to click and follow. I just don't know if it's possible. I'm interested to know myself.

Comment: @JeffC Yes, it takes time so i wanna know it before clicking. I also didn't know if it was possible so I made this question.